# Upload Android Source Code into real device

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I have build whole android source code...with the help of make command....for dream htc product...now i want to deploy those files(system.img,recovery.img,userdata.img,boot.img) in my real device htc t mobile g1...how can i deploy those files....?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're just starting out with Android, in which case it would be very wise to use the  [Android Development Tools Plugin for Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html), which I'm guessing you're not doing currently.

Once you install that, deploying to your application to your Android device is as simple as right clicking the project in Eclipse, and selecting "Run As -> Android Application".

Note: make sure you enable debugging on your phone: "Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging".

Comment: Read the question again, please. He talks about android as the open source project and he has build is own custom rom, not an android application...

Answer (score 0):

I guess what u wanna do is create a flashable zip file and install it via recovery,
You need to get the Android Kitchen (provided you have a Linux box or else you have to install cygwin on windows)goto http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=633246
and download the kitchen execute the `.menu` and you'll find a really long menu that may help you to package the files into a flashable zip file,
and since you are using HTC Dream install the amon ra's custom recovery(you need to root the device first,install the `universal AndRoot` from play store and root your device)copy the file to your sdcard and rename it as `recovery.img` if you have a terminal emulator app goto the prompt and type `flash_image recovery /sdcard/recovery.img` and if you are having trouble with the `flash_image` binary install busyBox from app store and that should solve the problem,
and after the recovery had been installed goto the terminal app or `adb` window then type `reboot recovery` or turn on the device by holding home key and in the recovery window do a complete wipe and select the option `flash zip archive` or something, browse the zip file you have created using the kitchen from the sdcard and select yes wait for the process to complete. hope this helps you